# Copy div tag with its info and send to next page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to copy a div-tag with all of it's information and then post it to the next page on my site? The information in the divtag is dynamic so if it's possible to copy the div-tag it would be a nice solution.

The information in the div is information from a form that has been split in half and then posted separately because the one half that i want to copy was information that shouldn't be updated and the other half was information that should be updated. I then posted the updated form again to the new page and i want to be able to reach the information from the half that was not updated on my new site.

Comment: Why not just build that section as a partial in both pages?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only post forms or files. Perhaps if you'd stick the div's contents in a hidden input element upon post.